# Using Joda, How do I determine if a given date is between time x and a time 3 hours earlier than x?

Tags: java, jodatime

What is the simplest way to use Joda time and get something like the following behavior:

```
public boolean check( DateTime checkTime )
{
    DateTime someTime = new DateTime(); //set to "now" for sake of example
    return checkTime.isBefore( someTime ) && checkTime.notMoreThanThreeHoursBefore( someTime );
}
```

So if `someTime` is set to 15:00 and `checkTime` is set to 12:15 it should return true.

If `someTime` is set to 15:00 and `checkTime` is set to 11:45 it should return false because `checkTime` is more than 3 hours before `someTime`.

If `someTime` is set to 15:00 and `checkTime` is set to 15:15 it should return false because `checkTime` is after `someTime`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

After some playing around, I found this which reads nicely:

```
return new Interval( someTime.minusHours( 3 ), someTime ).contains( checkTime );
```

Comment: Yup, good call. I'd forgotten about Interval. Handy that it's inclusive of the start and exclusive of the end :)

Answer (score 6):

Easy:

```
DateTime someTime = new DateTime();
DateTime earliest = someTime.minusHours(3);

if (earliest.compareTo(checkTime) <= 0 && checkTime.compareTo(someTime) < 0)
```

I've used `compareTo` as there's no `isBeforeOrEqual` or `isAfterOrEqual` - but you can use `compareTo` for any relation.

I suspect it was just `minusHours` that you were after though :)

Comment: You can do `x.isBeforeOrEqual(y)` by doing `!y.isAfter(x)` - although it's a bit obtuse.

Comment: @dty Actually this is wrong! As `x.isBeforeOrEqual(y)` means `y` is **not before** `x`. That corresponds to: `!y.isBefore(x)`. This comment stayed here for more than 5 years and no one noticed the error. Whoa!